# How can you convert an array([]) object, into an array([[]]) object?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to convert

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

to

```
array([[0,1,2,3,4,5]])
```

But I can't find any information online. Are there a any solution to this?

Comment: [np.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, I used np.array() to wrap it but it just left me with what I had previously

Comment: You want either `np.expand_dims(a, 0)` or `a[None]`, or maybe `np.atleast_2d(a)` if you want to handle scalars and arrays that already *are* 2D

Comment: @user3483203 I think this should be an answer

Comment: reshape(arr, (1,5)) is also useful.  Look at the shape of the desired array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[None]
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html `The newaxis object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. newaxis is an alias for ‘None’, and ‘None’ can be used in place of this with the same result.`